# PHP search array column for 2 values using in_array()

Tags: php, arrays

How do I search for 2 values in the same record using in_array()?
For example I want to search for 'AuthorNiceName' value and 'AuthorType' value.

The below code does not work how I would like. It should return "EU TEST" but it returns "CP TEST".

Thanks in advance.

```
 $authors = array(
        array(
            'AuthorName' => 'John Smith',
            'AuthorNiceName' => 'john-smith',
            'AuthorType' => 'CP'
        ),
        array(
            'AuthorName' => 'Joe Bloggs',
            'AuthorNiceName' => 'joe-bloggs',
            'AuthorType' => 'EU'
        ),
    );



    if (in_array('joe-bloggs', array_column($authors, 'AuthorNiceName')) && in_array('EU', array_column($authors, 'AuthorType'))) {
        $authorType = 'CP TEST';
    }
    else {
        $authorType = 'EU TEST';
    }

    echo $authorType;
```

UPDATE: My latest code using @Philipp's suggestion which I adjusted slightly. However it doesn't work, if there are other users with the same 'AuthorType' it returns "no match"?

```
$authors = array( //TODO
    array(
        'AuthorName' => 'John Smith',
        'AuthorNiceName' => 'john-smith',
        'AuthorType' => 'CP'
    ),
    array(
        'AuthorName' => 'Joe Bloggs',
        'AuthorNiceName' => 'joe-bloggs',
        'AuthorType' => 'EU'
    ),
    array(
        'AuthorName' => 'Matt Bat',
        'AuthorNiceName' => 'matt-bat',
        'AuthorType' => 'EU'
    ),    
);

$name = 'joe-bloggs';
$type = 'EU';
foreach ($authors as $author) {
    if ($author['AuthorNiceName'] == $name && $author['AuthorType'] == 'EU') {
        $authorType = 'EU Test';
    }
   elseif ($author['AuthorNiceName'] == $name && $author['AuthorType'] == 'CP') {
        $authorType = 'CP Test';
    }
    else {
        $authorType = 'no match';
    }

}

echo $authorType; //returns "not match". it should return "EU Test".
```

Comment: It's working correctly and doing exactly what you coded it to do.

Comment: Yes however I want it to search for "joe-bloggs" and "EU" within the same record? I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, you should use a loop for what you want

```
$name = 'joe-bloggs';
$type = 'EU';
foreach ($authors as $author) {
    if ($author['AuthorNiceName'] == $name && $author['AuthorType'] == $type) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

using in_array with array_column looses the information if the result is from the same column. Using array_search, you could also compare the index of the columns, but this seems like a bad solution...

---

#### Update

The problem with your update is, you overwrite the `$authorType` var, after you set the correct value. You should check, if an value is already set and only then set a new value.

```
$name = 'joe-bloggs';
$authorType = false;
foreach ($authors as $author) {
    if ($author['AuthorNiceName'] == $name && $author['AuthorType'] == 'EU') {
        $authorType = 'EU Test';
    } elseif ($author['AuthorNiceName'] == $name && $author['AuthorType'] == 'CP') {
        $authorType = 'CP Test';
    }
}

if ($authorType === false) {
    echo 'no match';
} else {
    echo $authorType;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although that doesn't seem to work if there are other authors with the same 'AuthorType'.

For example:

$authors = array( //TODO
    array(
        'AuthorName' => 'John Smith',
        'AuthorNiceName' => 'john-smith',
        'AuthorType' => 'CP'
    ),
    array(
        'AuthorName' => 'Joe Bloggs',
        'AuthorNiceName' => 'joe-bloggs',
        'AuthorType' => 'EU'
    ),
    array(
        'AuthorName' => 'Matt Bat',
        'AuthorNiceName' => 'matt-bat',
        'AuthorType' => 'EU'
    ),    
);

Comment: @ianhman what do you mean with don't work? what is the code supposed to do, if there are multiple authors with the same type?

Comment: Please see my updated my question with the latest code.